# Do not prohibit write access to files, but discard them?

Tags: linux, lucene, geonetwork

I have a Lucene index (from Geonetwork 2.10.4) with the following files.

```
_8yw_f.del           _8yw_Lucene41_0.pos  _8yx.cfe    _8yy.si   _8z0.si   _8z2.si   _8z4.si   _8z7.si   _8za.si   _8zc.si   _8ze.si       write.lock
_8yw.fdt             _8yw_Lucene41_0.tim  _8yx.cfs    _8yz.cfe  _8z1.cfe  _8z3.cfe  _8z6.cfe  _8z9.cfe  _8zb.cfe  _8zd.cfe  _8zf.cfe
_8yw.fdx             _8yw_Lucene41_0.tip  _8yx.si     _8yz.cfs  _8z1.cfs  _8z3.cfs  _8z6.cfs  _8z9.cfs  _8zb.cfs  _8zd.cfs  _8zf.cfs
_8yw.fnm             _8yw_nrm.cfe         _8yy_1.del  _8yz.si   _8z1.si   _8z3.si   _8z6.si   _8z9.si   _8zb.si   _8zd.si   _8zf.si
_8yw_Lucene41_0.doc  _8yw_nrm.cfs         _8yy.cfe    _8z0.cfe  _8z2.cfe  _8z4.cfe  _8z7.cfe  _8za.cfe  _8zc.cfe  _8ze.cfe  segments_57i
_8yw_Lucene41_0.pay  _8yw.si              _8yy.cfs    _8z0.cfs  _8z2.cfs  _8z4.cfs  _8z7.cfs  _8za.cfs  _8zc.cfs  _8ze.cfs  segments.gen
```

When I set the folder or files to read-only, Geonetwork throws a SEVERE error. Since I don't want to change the Tomcat app, I left that error out for now.

Now my idea/question: Is there a way in Linux (Ubuntu etc.) to discard write operations and allow read operations? (`chmod 0444` does not lead to the goal.) I'm thinking of a program or layer between the Tomcat app and the file system that discards write operations. So Geonetwork writes something into the index, but in reality this writing process is discarded and the index does not change or remains as it was before the writing process.

Comment: I found [FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) and [fusepy](https://github.com/fusepy/fusepy). Lets see if I can do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

## First attempt -- fusepy -- failed

### Tweak the example

I just took

```
 def write(self, path, buf, offset, fh):
     os.lseek(fh, offset, os.SEEK_SET)
     return os.write(fh, buf)
```

from

https://medium.com/the-python-corner/writing-a-fuse-filesystem-in-python-5e0f2de3a813

or more precisely from

https://github.com/skorokithakis/python-fuse-sample/blob/master/passthrough.py

and replaced it with

```
def write(self, path, buf, offset, fh):
    print('path: ', path, 'len(buf): ', len(buf), 'offset: ', offset)
    return len(buf)
```

which means that nothing is written to any file or fh (= file handle) in the mounted path. (`os.write(...)` will normally return the length of the written bytes.)

### Hide the index behind my own file system

To mount it I used

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/
mv ./index/ ./index_for_fuse/
mkdir ./index/
python3 /opt/python-fuse-sample/passthrough.py ./index_for_fuse/ ./index/
```

### Error 1

```
2018-07-24 12:02:07,300 ERROR [jeeves.engine] - {Stack=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create directory: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/index
        at org.fao.geonet.GeonetworkDataDirectory.setResourceDir(GeonetworkDataDirectory.java:323)
        at org.fao.geonet.GeonetworkDataDirectory.setDataDirectory(GeonetworkDataDirectory.java:201)
        at org.fao.geonet.GeonetworkDataDirectory.<init>(GeonetworkDataDirectory.java:61)
        at org.fao.geonet.Geonetwork.start(Geonetwork.java:165)
        at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.initAppHandler(JeevesEngine.java:600)
        at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.init(JeevesEngine.java:206)
        at jeeves.server.sources.http.JeevesServlet.init(JeevesServlet.java:91)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1184)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5539)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
, Exception=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create directory: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/index, Message=Unable to create directory: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/index, Handler=org.fao.geonet.Geonetwork, Error=Raised exception while starting appl handler. Skipped.}
```

### Solution 1

Put this in code:

```
FUSE(Passthrough(root), mountpoint, nothreads=True, foreground=True, debug=True, allow_other=True)
```

Especially the `allow_other=True` is important, so Tomcat can write into the folder. Found here:

https://github.com/fusepy/fusepy/wiki/Sharing-fusepy-mount-via-Samba

### Error 2

```
Exception in thread "Lucene Merge Thread #0" org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: MMapIndexInput(path="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/index/taxonomy/_1.fnm")
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:541)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:514)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: MMapIndexInput(path="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/index/taxonomy/_1.fnm")
        at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.readByte(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:77)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readInt(DataInput.java:84)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.readInt(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:128)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:126)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40FieldInfosReader.read(Lucene40FieldInfosReader.java:56)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:101)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:57)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndLiveDocs.getMergeReader(ReadersAndLiveDocs.java:153)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:3635)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3303)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:401)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:478)
```

### No solution 2

It looks like the merger thread cannot merge the index because he checks what he writes. ^^

---

## Second attempt -- BASH :)

To be continued.